Change widget of modelformset field to RadioSelect without defining a form object?
In Django, I am instantiating a modelformset as follows (straight from here):
    MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        MyModel,
        fields=["one", "two", "three"],
        extra=0)
    fs = MyFormSet(queryset=MyModel.objects.filter(field=a_value))

So, no form object at all, it just picks the fields I want.
However, one of those fields (say "two") is rendered as a drop-down, and I want it as a RadioSelect.
Is there a way to change the widget of "two" to RadioSelect in a simple way, or do I have to declare a form object to customize that?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets
